# Wordpress Rest API - add user capability

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

Is there any way to add a capability to user using the Rest API?

I am creating the user this way:

```
$.ajax( {
    url: Slug_API_Settings.root + ‘wp/v2/users/’,
    method: ‘POST’,
    beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader( ‘X-WP-Nonce’, Slug_API_Settings.nonce );
    },
    data:{
        email: ‘someone@somewhere.net’,
        username: ‘someone’,
        password: Math.random().toString(36).substring(7)
    }
    })
    .done( function ( response ) {
        console.log( response );
     })
```

Then I need to assign the capability to new user. Does anyone have a example of that?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the user role and capability by the WordPress REST API to the new users as per below code:

```
$.ajax( {
url: Slug_API_Settings.root + ‘wp/v2/users/’,
method: ‘POST’,
beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader( ‘X-WP-Nonce’, Slug_API_Settings.nonce );
},
data:{
    email: ‘someone@somewhere.net’,
    username: ‘someone’,
    password: Math.random().toString(36).substring(7),
    roles: ‘contributor’
}
})
.done( function ( response ) {
    console.log( response );
 })
```

Roles `conotributor` have the capabilities like `delete_posts`, `edit_posts` and `read` you can also assign users to extra capabilities using `extra_capabilities` parameter.

You can also refer the WordPress API Official Docs [Here](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/#schema-meta)

Please also refer the Roles and Capabilities [Here.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities)

Comment: Thanks very much for the help! I'll try that.

Comment: Let me know here..! If you will face any issue with this.